# Query state in React, and setState or update if exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add Transactions to an app in React, and I want to organise these transactions by year, then month, so the structure would be the following:

```
{
  "2016" : {
    "january": {
      "transaction1": transaction,
      "transaction2": transaction,
      "transaction3": transaction
    },
    "february" : {
      "transaction1": transaction,
      "transaction2": transaction,
      "transaction3": transaction
    }
  }
}
```

I have a function in my App that receives a transaction object, which I then want to add to the transactions state to the relevant year/month.

```
addTransaction(transaction) {
    const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    var month = monthNames[(new Date()).getMonth()];
    console.log(
      this.state.transactions != null;
    );
    // check year exists?
    // add if necessary
    // check month exists?
    // add if necessary
  }
```

What I am trying to work out is:

- How can i query whether the year exists in the `transactions` state object
- I then need to apply it to the correct year and month if it does exist, or
- Add the new year and month if it doesn't

**UPDATE:**
I have updated `addTransaction`, and am trying to create the year (not adding the month in yet) and then add the transaction to that, but it's not creating the year and I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'transaction-1453842528740' of undefined`

```
addTransaction(transaction) {
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    var month = monthNames[(new Date()).getMonth()];

    if (year in this.state.transactions) {
      // add to year
    } else {
      this.state.transactions[year]['transaction-' + timestamp] = transaction;
    }

    this.setState({
      transactions: { [year]: this.state.transactions[year] }
    });
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just move the `setState` line into your `else` block; you should not be manipulating state directly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way you'd do it if you like mutating your objects:

```
const transactions = this.state.transactions;
// get or create the year object
const yearObject = transactions[year] || (transactions[year] = {});
// get or create the month object
const monthObject = yearObject[month] || (yearObject[month] = {});
// add the transaction
const transactionId = `transaction-${timestamp}`;
monthObject[transactionId] = transaction;
this.setState({ transactions });
```

And this is how you'd do it in an immutable style (which would let you make your component pure:

```
const transactions = this.state.transactions;
// get or create the year object
const yearObject = transactions[year] || {};
// get or create the month object
const monthObject = yearObject[month] || {};
// add the transaction
const transactionId = `transaction-${timestamp}`;

const newTransactions = {
    // copy the old object
    ...transactions,
    // assign a copy of the year object
    [year]: {
        // copy the old year object
        ...yearObject,
        // assign a copy of the month object
        [month]: {
            // copy the old month object
            ...monthObject,
            // add the new transaction
            [transactionId]: transaction
        }
    }
};

// assign our new object
this.setState({ transactions: newTransactions });
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you Brandon :) Can I ask, regarding the technique to copy the existing transaction/year/month object with ...transactions etc... what is this called? Is there anything in the React docs on this so I can read up? Thanks again.

Comment: It is JavaScript ES7 syntax.  Object spread operator I believe it is called. Based on your code sample it looks like you are using Babel, so it should work as long as you have it enabled and you can read about the syntax on their website.

Comment: Thank you - and yes, using Babel.

Answer (score 2):

These are JavaScript questions, which I'll answer below. In the ReactJS context, you may only update top-level objects within the component's state. So in your example, you cannot just update "january"; you have to replace "2016" completely.

> 1. How can i query whether the year exists in the transactions state object

```
!!object[key]
```

returns **true** where present. So, for example,

```
a = {
  "2016" : {
    "january": {
      "transaction1": 1,
      "transaction2": 2,
      "transaction3": 3
    },
    "february" : {
      "transaction1": 4,
      "transaction2": 5,
      "transaction3": 6
    }
  }
}
!!a["2016"]
```

returns **true**, and

```
!!a["2015"]
```

returns **false**.

> 2. I then need to apply it to the correct year and month if it does exist, or Add the new year and month if it doesn't

Just create a new top-level "2016" object. This means passing a modified version of your structure to setState(). It might seem inefficient, but it works.

Comment: There is a `in` operator to check key presence. `!!` looks confusing and may have false-negatives.

Comment: Thanks a lot John, definitely getting there, however I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'transaction-1453842661026' of undefined` with the updated code. (Have edited my original post with updated code. The code I am using is not setting the year and transaction. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You seem to be trying to set **this.state.transactions** directly, which won't work in ReactJS. You have to use **this.setState({ transactions: ... });** supplying a complete object for **transactions**. That object is a copy of this.state.transactions, modified as you need it.

Comment: I've just seen the 'immutable' version by @Brandon, in the other proposed solution; I recommend that.